# Box2D won't work with Python

Tags: python, box2d, traceback

I have installed Python 2.6.6 and Box2D 2.0.2b1. And can't create box2d world - b2World().

Simple example:

```
import Box2D
Box2D.b2World()
```

No matter what I type into function b2World, I received this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    Box2D.b2World()
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\Box2D\Box2D.py", line 4350, in __init__
    _Box2D.b2World_swiginit(self,_Box2D.new_b2World(*args))
TypeError: new_b2World expected 3 arguments, got 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like:

```
world = b2World(gravity=(0,-10), doSleep=True)
```

I had a look at the 2.0.2 version and it looks like you should pass your arguments like this:

```
worldAABB=box2d.b2AABB()
worldAABB.lowerBound = (-100.0, -100.0)
worldAABB.upperBound = ( 100.0, 100.0)
gravity = (0.0, -10.0)
world = box2d.b2World(worldAABB, gravity, True)
```

Comment: As I wrote above, no matter what code is written into function I got error message. In your case I got: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    world = Box2D.b2World(gravity=(0,-10), doSleep=True)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'doSleep'`

Comment: Where did you get 2.0.2b1 from? I just find 2.0.1, 2.1.2, 2.1.3 and 2.2.X series. Did you try to upgrade?

Comment: No I haven't updated it yet, but I suppose I should. 2.0.2b1 can be found here http://code.google.com/p/pybox2d/downloads/detail?name=Box2D-2.0.2b1.win32-py2.6.exe&can=1&q=

Comment: It's working. Thanks a lot. But it seems a bit complicated than other versions. Isn't it a disadvantage?